# Determine SSRS report count and have user validate before running

Tags: reporting-services

I have a large SSRS report with 30+ parameters. When executed, the report calls a back end SQL stored procedure to pull the result set. Depending on what parameters have been chosen, this report set can be very large and take multiple minutes to generate. However, getting the count of this result set tends to be very quick.

I would like a way to display the count of the result set to the user when they click the "View Report" button (perhaps via a message box). Additionally, I'd like a way for them to confirm whether they still want to run the report after the count has been shown.

Is this possible in SSRS?

Comment: You would probably have to create a separate process that uses the SQL in the SSRS report to make a call that just returns a count of records.

Comment: So, you want to run the report 2 times, essentially, before showing the user the results. Have a textbox in the header to show the `CountRows("datasetname")` and only run the report once.